# How do I make one row in a resultset from 2 related rows in a table

Tags: sql, t-sql

Every time there is a transaction in our system we write two rows in a table that captures the original value of Code and a new value for Code and then the same Transaction_ID for both rows.

**Table structure:**

```
History_ID primary key
Transaction_ID int
Code varchar(3)
```

**Sample Data:**

```
1   12345     ABC
2   12345     DEF
```

I need a query that will bring back 1 row by joining the 2 rows with the same Transaction_ID.  The result set should have the Code column labled 'Old Code' for the first row that was inserted and a column labled 'New Code' for then 2nd row that was inserted.

**Sample output:**

```
Transaction Old Code New Code
12345       ABC      DEF
```

I have tried using a subquery but I always get back 2 rows.  I'm using SQL Server.

Comment: What happens the next time the code is changed, DEF -> GHI? Is that a new transaction (and transaction_ID) or the same?

Comment: A new transaction with a new transaction id.  The most and least number of rows with the same transaction id will be 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alias the same table multiple times in a query.  In this case join the two instances of transactions by the Transaction_Id and have the section instance be the newer one by retrieving a row with a greater history id.

```
SELECT a.Transaction_ID, a.Code [OldCode], b.Code [NewCode]
FROM trx a
INNER JOIN trx b ON b.Transaction_ID = a.Transaction_ID
AND b.HistoryId > a.HistoryId
```

This assumes that there are only two rows per transaction Id.  If you had a sequence of transaction events, then this would not work, and you'd have to get a bit more sophisticated.

Answer (score 1):

Join the table with itself

```
SELECT h1.transaction_id, h1.code as 'New Code', h2.code as 'Old Code'
FROM history h1
JOIN history h2 ON h1.transaction_id = h2.transaction_id AND h1.history_id > h2.history_id
```

Comment: Thank you, I guess Daniel hit the Send button a few seconds before you did but they are both the right answer.